# backend localhost:4000 url is working fine to load the user but not the deployed backend url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, azure, deployment

I deployed the backend on azure and changed the frontend url every thing working fine except load user. i.e:- when I refresh my page the user state gets lost.
This is MERN project.  I am using jwt authentication.

in api.js
`export const API_URL = "http://localhost:4000"`  is working fine but when I change my backend url `export const API_URL = "http://<deployed_url>"`
the it's not working.

```
//Load  User
export const LoadUser =() => async (dispatch)=>{
    try{
        dispatch({ type:LOAD_USER_REQUEST })

        const { data } =  await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/me`)

        dispatch({type:LOAD_USER_SUCCESS, payload:data.user})
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({ type:LOAD_USER_FAIL, payload:error.response.data.message });
    }
}
```

```
const sendToken = (user,statusCode, res) =>{
    const token = user.getJWTToken();

    //options for cookie
    const options = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true,
    };

    res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token,options).json({
        success:true,
        user,
        token,
    })
}

module.exports = sendToken;
```

```
exports.isAuthenticatedUser =  catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next)=>{
    const {token} = req.cookies;

    if(!token) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("please Login to access this resource",401));
    }

    const decodedData = jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET);

   req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);

   next();

})
```

```
router.route('/me').get(isAuthenticatedUser ,getUserDetails)
```

rest all apis are working except this one this is saying 401 Unauthorized when I used deployed one.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the process.env.JWT_SECRET value is the same in both your backend code and the deployed environment. If they don't match, the token verification will fail, resulting in a 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: ya  `JWT_SECRET` is same in deployed env and in development @tabish2k

Comment: in request Header Cookie is not there when I use backend deployed url. in network tab

Comment: If the cookie header is not present in the request headers when using the deployed backend URL it indicates that the cookie is not being sent from the frontend to the backend during the request.

Comment: ya but with this url `export const API_URL = "http://localhost:4000"` it works. Cookie is present

Comment: Verify the deployed URL is correct and accessible and check if you can directly access the backend APIs using the deployed URL. If the APIs are not accessible, there may be an issue with the deployment setup or server configuration.

Comment: yes backend apis are accessible using deployed url

Comment: make sure that the deployed backend is correctly verifying the JWT token received from the frontend and double-check that the process.env.JWT_SECRET value is properly set in the Azure environment configuration and matches the value used to sign the token.

Comment: that's the issue cookie is not being sent with the deployed url. JWT_SECRET is correct I matched it

Comment: when I use localhost Url then it's working but not with the backend url